# Date Difference In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder why finding the difference between the upcoming day and the current day is returning 0 instead of 1. Let's say that the upcoming day is in the format `2022-11-09 00:00:00.000` and the current day is assumed using `DateTime.now()`. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var _dateTime = '2022-11-09 00:00:00.000';
  var diff = DateTime.parse(_dateTime.toString())
      .difference(DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toString()))
      .inDays;
  print(diff);
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly working for me. Can you check that again.

Comment: Isn't it a UTC issue when creating Datetime.now?

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked it and found a solution. But it may not be the best one but it works. Just add +1 to `diff` and that's all. If you change `_dateTime` to other dates like '2022-11-10' or more future days, it's working like a charm. Hope that it works for you.